# Problems when @2x is not exactly 2x

Tags: ios, image, retina-display

I have set of images with @2x counterparts, but @2x arent the exact size they should be. 
The 2x are smaller than they should be. 
Width or height is smaller by 1px or 2px.

Images are sliced UI which is tightly fitted.

Is there something to worry about?
Can this cause problems on retina like unexpected spaces?

Comment: the `@2x` naming convention just indicates to the iOS for loading an image for the actual screen resolution. the two image could be totally different (e.g. content, size, ect...), iOS does not really care about it.

Comment: To add to @holex's comment, just make sure you're not hardcoding in any height / width size information. If you force an image to display at a certain size, and the image isn't that size, the image can be stretched or cropped depending on your UIImageView's configuration.

Comment: Size is set in IB = hardcoded.

Answer (score 1):

Typically `@2x` images will be exactly twice the size of regular images but it is perfectly fine for them not to be exactly twice the size. It depends on how the images are being used.

One case where you want to be careful is with `UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:`. You need to make sure the actual size of both images are appropriate for the insets you specify.